# Xcode not supported for iOS 11.3 by Xcode 9.2 needed 9.3

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9.3

Apparently, with the latest IOS update, my version of Xcode could not build due to the following error.

> Could not locate device support files. This iPhone 7 Plus (Model 1661, 1784, 1785, 1786) is running iOS 11.3 (15E216), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

Tried to install Xcode 9.3 via this link https://developer.apple.com/download/more/. But as it turns out, my Mac OS version sees the update as an incompatible version. Running on **Sierra 10.12.6**

Comment: You need to update to Xcode 9.3

Comment: Download the latest Xcode-Beta version on Apple Developer, it will solve this issue.

Comment: @Maximelc could you share a screen shot of the download i should get

Comment: @alphapilgrim You should have something like this [Screen Shot](https://imgur.com/d90SVUu).

Comment: Been there... Not fun. Developers cannot be too far behind, once the machine cannot update to the latest macOS, it's time to update the hardware. It use to be (relatively) safe to be one macOS version behind. That is no longer true.. It's better to not update iOS devices before updating Xcode. Xcode can build on older iOS, the reverse will not work.

Comment: Xcode 9.3 is NOW released. Goto App store and update. Not all of my machines got notified of the update being available for some unknown reason but it was simply a matter of installing it again.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Another option is to download the 11.3 device support at:

[iOS 11.3 (15E217)](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport/issues/7)

And don't forget to remove "(15E217)" from folder name, so it became "11.3". Restart Xcode afterwards.

[image]

**Where to paste it**  according to comment of EdwardM

For those that don't know where to paste the contents of the zipped file. Find your Applications icon in the dock, right-click, "Open Applications". The folder will open in Finder. Right-click Xcode > Show Package Contents. Then go to Developer > Platforms > iPhoneOS.platform > DeviceSupport

Comment: For those that don't know where to paste the contents of the zipped file. Find your Applications icon in the dock, right-click, "Open Applications". The folder will open in Finder. Right-click Xcode > Show Package Contents. Then go to Developer > Platforms > iPhoneOS.platform > DeviceSupport

Comment: Cmd+Space -> Enter this string "/Applications/Xcode9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/", change the Xcode to whichever version you have

Comment: For some reason this isn't working with one of my mac, but worked on other, strange (both have XCode 9.2)

Comment: I was unable to paste it, so I had to use `sudo mkdir` and `sudo cp` to put the files in the right place. For those who need any help, here's more detail: https://medium.com/@namenotrequired/cannot-paste-into-iphoneos-platform-devicesupport-c3683cd82ed

Comment: Restarting Xcode didn't work for me. I had to also restart my Mac for these changes to take effect.

Answer (score 34):

I have the same problem, OS Sierra trying to run iPhone SE with 10.3 using Xcode 9.2 and I don't have the resources to update to High Sierra and Xcode 9.3.

Solution:

1. Find your friends who have Xcode 9.3
2. Ask them to right click on Xcode, Show Package Contents then navigate to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.3 (15E217)`
3. Copy the `11.3 (15E217)` folder to your old Xcode (9.2) with the same file hierarchy

Now you have Xcode 9.2 with iOS 11.3.

Comment: If you built outside Xcode originally i.e. a Cordova App, you may need to build again before changes take effect

Comment: This also happened to me when I installed Xcode 10 beside Xcode 9.3. And copying the device support from Xcode 10 to 9.3 made it work.

Answer (score 30):

I just give you a device support file for iOS [11.4 (15F79)](http://www.mediafire.com/file/7m25vq8l35eplws/11.4_%252815F79%2529.zip/file).
which just on XCode version 9.4 (9F1027a)

**Updated on 5 Oct 2018:**

- Xcode 10.0 (10A255) - [iOS 12.0 (16A366)](http://www.mediafire.com/file/shoc26i32dchc95/12.0_%252816A366%2529.zip/file) [Updated 21 Sep: @Nik
  Burns confirmed that works]
- Xcode 10.1 beta 2 (10O35n) - [iOS 12.1 (16B5068g)](https://www.mediafire.com/file/24ol8p4o4swbxup/12.1_%2816B5068g%29.zip/file) [Please give me feedback if that works]

Comment: 11.3.1 (15E302) is available ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have it.

Comment: Which you should put in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` assuming Xcode.app is in `/Applications`

Comment: ios12 works great, thanks. Worth noting that the Xcode app itself needs right clicking to show package contents, then navigate to iPhoneOS.platform as per above comment.

Comment: @NikBurns Thanks for your confirm. I think what you're saying kl.woon already answered above. So I don't want to repeat it again. :D

Answer (score 7):

I have macOS 10.12.6

You can download Xcode 9.3 from https://developer.apple.com/download/
and extract the "**11.3 (15E217)**" folder from it

The fix really works.

Answer (score 2):

please add both of "11.3 (15E216)" and "11.3 (15E217)" 
keep all of them inside /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled upon the same problem, where I basically updated my iPhone X to the newest OS version, and (for reasons I will not go into) had to run the app on Xcode 9.2.

This thread was helpful, but there's one small caveat that even though I downloaded the newest support files from the [provided Github project](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport), and put them in the appropriate folder, I was still getting this error:

[image]

Say for example you’ve downloaded 11.4 (15F79) but after restarting and running again you get an error mentioning something like 11.4.1 (15G77).

The solution, as I wrote [here](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ios/run-app-iphone-newest-os-version-via-older-version-xcode/), was to just **rename the folder** (so, rename `11.4 (15F79)` to `11.4.1 (15G77)`), restart Xcode and voila, it works!

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have macOS 10.13.4
2. I downloaded Xcode 9.3
3. Here you have the "11.3 (15E217)"  it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Quicker/Smaller Fix**

This is probably due to outdated Xcode, if you don't want a big `Xcode` update due to limited storage/time then you can manually download the required support files instead of the whole update.

1. Download the files (depend on iOS veersion) from [here](https://github.com/Yatko/iOS-device-support-files)
2. And then paste the downloaded files in below directory `/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`