# device support files for iOS 11.4 (15F79)

Tags: xcode

After updated my iPhone to 11.4, I found out that current version (Version 9.3 (9E145)) of Xcode do not have device support files for iOS 11.4 (15F79). Is there anything I can or should do to remedy this issue?

Answer (score 45):

- [Download image file 11.4 (15F79)](https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/releases/tag/11.4)

  Paste it here in your Xcode:
  Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

Also you can download latest and earlier version [HERE](https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/releases)

Comment: Just to add, as the bottom comments have said; you can donload the image file from Xcode 9.4 and then copy `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.4` into the same place in your current Xcode installation. Or you can simply use Xcode 9.4 as your XCode version.

Comment: Where we can download ? Paste Download link please

Comment: I had to restart XCode for it to work, (maybe it was obvious but not for me)

Answer (score 9):

**[The latest version of XCode](https://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/xcode/id497799835)** (version 9.4) was released on the 29th of May, which has support for iOS 11.4. You simply need to update XCode as well.

XCode 9.4 brings support for:

- Swift 4.1
- iOS 11.4
- watchOS 4.3
- tvOS 11.4
- High Sierra 10.13.4

Answer (score 4):

Go to Apple Developer site and download Xcode 9.4.zip and decompress it and copy the folder:

Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.4 (15F79)

and paste it into the same directory of your current Xcode folder.

I recommend to download and use contents from Apple instead from unknown sites.

Answer (score 3):

iOS 12.0 (16A5288q) device support file

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eQA8-wKd6Zy0BDbQ8MJeupGkpoy1btz8

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't want to update my Xcode but my iPhone device updated automatically.
So i downloaded the latest XCode from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

1. Open the archived file using "Right Click" -> "Show package
   contents".
2. Copy the file from Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport to your Xcode.
3. Restart Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50596391/4569257) , just download the files and place the folder under /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform

Comment: The correct path is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` and don't forget to restart Xcode!

Answer (score 0):

If you not able to locate the Xcode.app in the Application folder, the easiest way is to `sudo find / -name Xcode.app -print` and copy the required device support file.

Please do restart the Xcode to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can download each SDK from this [github repository](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport) and then move it into Applications/Xcode App/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/