# many errors after updating xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9.4

After updating to Xcode 9.4, I started to receive some errors and I cannot even build it now. The errors are Apple Mach-o link error, dsymutil error, ditto error. The details of dysmutil error are below;

```
GenerateDSYMFile /Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Lingustica.app.dSYM /Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Lingustica.app/Lingustica
cd /Users/Serkan/Documents/Projects/lingustica/IOS/Code/Lingustica
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Lingustica.app/Lingustica -o /Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Lingustica.app.dSYM 

error: cannot parse the debug map for "/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Lingustica.app/Lingustica": No such file or directory
```

The details of Mach-o error:

```
Ld /Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Lingustica.app/Lingustica normal armv7
cd /Users/Serkan/Documents/Projects/lingustica/IOS/Code/Lingustica
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk -L/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Bolts -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/BoringSSL -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKLoginKit -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseAuth -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseCore -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseFirestore -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseMessaging -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseStorage -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseUI -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GTMOAuth2 -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Protobuf -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/SDWebImage -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/gRPC -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/gRPC-Core -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/gRPC-ProtoRPC -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/gRPC-RxLibrary -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/leveldb-library -F/Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/nanopb -F/Users/Serkan/Documents/Projects/lingustica/IOS/Code/Lingustica/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/Serkan/Documents/Projects/lingustica/IOS/Code/Lingustica/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/Serkan/Documents/Projects/lingustica/IOS/Code/Lingustica/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -FPods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks -filelist /Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Lingustica.build/Release-iphoneos/Lingustica.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Lingustica.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.1 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Lingustica.build/Release-iphoneos/Lingustica.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Lingustica_lto.o -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Lingustica.build/Release-iphoneos/Lingustica.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Lingustica.swiftmodule -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework Bolts -framework CoreText -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseFirestore -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework FirebaseStorage -framework FirebaseUI -framework Foundation -framework GRPCClient -framework GTMOAuth2 -framework GTMSessionFetcher -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework GoogleSignIn -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework GoogleUtilities -framework MeasurementNanoPB -framework MobileCoreServices -framework ProtoRPC -framework Protobuf -framework RxLibrary -framework SDWebImage -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework grpc -framework leveldb -framework nanopb -framework openssl -ObjC -framework Pods_Lingustica -framework MessageUI -framework QuartzCore -framework StoreKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Lingustica.build/Release-iphoneos/Lingustica.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Lingustica_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Lingustica.app/Lingustica

ld: file not found: /Users/Serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lingustica-dtyxfwgrcmnnhzejeydnmtsnxwkt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Lingustica.build/Release-iphoneos/Lingustica.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Sentence.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried followings but no result :(

1) Clean and build

2) Enable bitcode: no

3) Valid architectures: delete arm7 and arm64, only left armv7

4) pod update

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve created another project and copy all the old files into the new one. I’ve installed the same pods. Nothing changed from the old project. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your DerivedData folder? It is located in `/Users/Your_User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. After, just recompile your app, and see if it works.

You should also look for any duplicate files, SDKs, classes, variables, etc.

If this does not work and you are using Cocoa pods, you can run `pod cache clear` and then `pod install` to reinstall your pods.

Finally, if this doesn't work, and you have source control enabled, you can try to remove your local copy and then fetch your project again.

Comment: Have you also tried to see if you have any duplicate files and/or duplicate SDKs?

Comment: Yes, I checked. No duplicates

Comment: Try to run `pod cache clean` and then `pod install`. You may have a problem with your pods.

Comment: I did but it didn't work too. I've also deleted all pods using https://stackoverflow.com/a/16427883/4932115 and then reinstall but there are still same errors.

Comment: Maybe you could try to fetch your project after removing it from your computer (if you are using git or another form of source control).

Answer (score 0):

Please share your pod list, some of them have double info.plsit files that causes this problem in xcode 9, plus, try to go to "build pashes" and remove your info.plist from there, and one more question. what device and ios are you using?

Comment: pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'

Comment: Might be you are opening .xcodeproj file after installing pods. Close the project and open .xcworkspace file

Comment: Build pashes? You mean build phases? I couldn't find info.plist there. And I'm trying to build it in simulator (11.4). Not on real device.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633023/device-support-files-for-ios-11-4-15f79

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9.4 so 11.4 (15F79) Device support already exists.

Comment: well, if you share your project i will be more than happy to help, its hard to work on with little information